# When resizing window, site scales but then starts to crop off the right side

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, scale

I almost finished designing a new website. The site looks good on Desktop, iPad (portrait and landscape) but was cropping off the right side of some of the headings on iphone.  I added

```
body {
overflow-x:hidden;
min-width:360px; }
```

This fixed the headings from cropping - but the site still opens on iphone at 320px width and you have to pinch to zoom out to see the part that is cropped off the right hand side.

The problem can be demonstrated on a desktop browser also by re-sizing the window.  The responsive content of the page scales down and then suddenly stops scaling at the last minute and instead crops of the right edge of the page.

I also have viewport set as follows: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;"/>`

Not sure what other code would be useful. Here is the link to the site as is: link to site removed

I think the problem is I a have a large 100px heading font that can just fit into 360px width but becomes cropped at 320px. I tried using vw to scale the headings - this works, but i prefer the look of the bigger font on the smaller screen more then a scaled font.  Is there a way to force the iphone to open the page with a 360px width instead of 320px?

Comment: Can't you just decrease the font-size ?

Comment: In theory, yes.  But the font size is perfect on Desktop, and iPad.  Is there a way to only resize for iphone?

Comment: yes! using `media-query`, as `@media only screen
and (max-width : 380px) { /*override font-size here*/}` for mobile devices.

Comment: Here are CSS media queries for each type of devices: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: Thanks. Media-Query did the trick :)

Comment: Why do you set a min-width on body? Seems rather odd..

Comment: By setting min-width on the body, it would stop the cropping of titles that were too big to fit on a 320 width screen.  So the pages min-width was instead 360 - which could fit the titles.  BUT - the iphone would still be zoomed to 320, but I could pinch and zoom out to display the entire page nicely.  In anycase, I have instead used media-query to simply use a smaller font size on smaller screens - and have removed the min-width code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have only two ideas to fix that..

first, try to make some headers smaller..

second(main), I thing that You haven't got responsive images, but I don't know, try: `img {max-width: 90%; height: auto;},` that should work. :)

Comment: Thanks. Yes I resized my headers only for smaller screens using media-query.  This worked as I needed.  I know some of my images are responsive - I'll have to go through and check in-case some are not.